# Alternative to forward-word / backward-word to include symbols -- e.g., ***

Tags: emacs, elisp

My preferred method of indicating a location within a document that requires attention is with three asterisks `***`.  When it comes time to select the region containing the three asterisks using `shift+right-word` or `shift+left-word`, those functions skip over the three asterisks and move along to the next word.  When I peeked inside `bindings.el`, I saw that `left-word` and `right-word` are adaptations of `forward-word` and `backward-word`, that are traceable to built-in functions in the C source code.  Essentially, I'm looking for `left-word` and `right-word` that includes symbols such as three asterisks `***`.

Can anyone please suggest a way to have a function that jumps a word or symbols to the left, and a word or symbols to the right.  The function would need to behave similar to left-word and right-word so that I could select more than one word if the arrow keys are pressed more than one time -- e.g., `left-word-or-symbols` and `right-word-or-symbols`.

---

The following is a custom function based upon the helpful answer of below:

```lisp
(defvar lawlist-movement-syntax-table
  (let ((st (make-syntax-table)))
    ;; ` default = punctuation
    ;; ' default = punctuation
    ;; , default = punctuation
    ;; ; default = punctuation
    (modify-syntax-entry ?{ "." st)  ;; { = punctuation
    (modify-syntax-entry ?} "." st)  ;; } = punctuation
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\" "." st) ;; " = punctuation
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\\ "_" st) ;; \ = symbol
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\$ "_" st) ;; $ = symbol
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\% "_" st) ;; % = symbol
    st)
  "Syntax table used while executing custom movement functions.")

(defun lawlist-forward-entity ()
"http://stackoverflow.com/q/18675201/2112489"
(interactive "^")
  (with-syntax-table lawlist-movement-syntax-table
    (cond
      ((eolp)
        (forward-char))
      ((and
          (save-excursion (< 0 (skip-chars-forward " \t")))
          (not (region-active-p)))
        (skip-chars-forward " \t"))
      ((and
          (save-excursion (< 0 (skip-chars-forward " \t")))
          (region-active-p))
        (skip-chars-forward " \t")
        (cond
          ((save-excursion (< 0 (skip-syntax-forward "w")))
            (skip-syntax-forward "w"))
          ((save-excursion (< 0 (skip-syntax-forward ".")))
            (skip-syntax-forward "."))
          ((save-excursion (< 0 (skip-syntax-forward "_()")))
            (skip-syntax-forward "_()"))))
      ((save-excursion (< 0 (skip-syntax-forward "w")))
        (skip-syntax-forward "w")
        (if (and
              (not (region-active-p))
              (save-excursion (< 0 (skip-chars-forward " \t"))))
          (skip-chars-forward " \t")))
      ((save-excursion (< 0 (skip-syntax-forward ".")))
        (skip-syntax-forward ".")
        (if (and
              (not (region-active-p))
              (save-excursion (< 0 (skip-chars-forward " \t"))))
          (skip-chars-forward " \t")))
      ((save-excursion (< 0 (skip-syntax-forward "_()")))
        (skip-syntax-forward "_()")
        (if (and
              (not (region-active-p))
              (save-excursion (< 0 (skip-chars-forward " \t"))))
          (skip-chars-forward " \t"))))))

(defun lawlist-backward-entity ()
"http://stackoverflow.com/q/18675201/2112489"
(interactive "^")
  (with-syntax-table lawlist-movement-syntax-table
    (cond
      ((bolp)
        (backward-char))
      ((save-excursion (> 0 (skip-chars-backward " \t")) (bolp))
        (skip-chars-backward " \t"))
      ((save-excursion (> 0 (skip-chars-backward " \t")) (> 0 (skip-syntax-backward "w")))
        (skip-chars-backward " \t")
        (skip-syntax-backward "w"))
      ((save-excursion (> 0 (skip-syntax-backward "w")))
        (skip-syntax-backward "w"))
      ((save-excursion (> 0 (skip-syntax-backward ".")))
        (skip-syntax-backward "."))
      ((save-excursion (> 0 (skip-chars-backward " \t")) (> 0 (skip-syntax-backward ".")))
        (skip-chars-backward " \t")
        (skip-syntax-backward "."))
      ((save-excursion (> 0 (skip-syntax-backward "_()")))
        (skip-syntax-backward "_()"))
      ((save-excursion (> 0 (skip-chars-backward " \t")) (> 0 (skip-syntax-backward "_()")))
        (skip-chars-backward " \t")
        (skip-syntax-backward "_()")))))
```

Comment: why not use `C-s` and `C-r` to find the asterisks and remove them that way?

Comment: @omouse  Since my being introduced to Emacs a few months ago, I've been on a quest to have a few basic word processing features that I had grown accustomed to over the years -- `right-word` / `left-word` were a good start, but not quite there.  `forward-symbol` and its converse came much closer, but not quite all the way.  The latest custom draft of `lawlist-forward-entity` / `lawlist-backward-entity` -- just about meets my personal preferences for moving the cursor.  Essentially, I like to treat symbols and punctuation separately from words, and skip over the whitespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add to the mode hook of the mode, where you are editing the text:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?* "w")
```

Read [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Table-Functions.html#Syntax-Table-Functions) for more info.

Note that this will make other functions treat asterisks as if they were word constituent (though, you'd probably want it, as you'd soon discover that not only the motion command behave contrary to how you want them to).

Another way to overload only these particular commands would be to advise them with `defadvice` and to temporarily alter the syntax table just for the duration of the function.

Comment: @lawlist yup, that's one way to do it.

Comment: I made a slight error and just corrected it with an underscore instead so that it restores the symbol constituent behavior:   http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html#Syntax-Class-Table   The edit to the question now works correctly as an alternative solution.

Comment: @lawlist you could use `char-syntax` to get the previously defined syntax class for the character, and then restore it to whatever it was before.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion -- I'll do some reading on how to implement `char-syntax`.

Answer (score 1):

You might like Emacs-24.4's `superword-mode`.

Comment: Thank you -- I'll check it out -- perhaps that code will give me some new ideas to further improve upon my custom word-processing functions for `lawlist-kill-word` ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958397/emacs-delete-whitespaces-or-a-word ); `lawlist-forward-entity` and `lawlist-backward-entity` ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675201/alternative-to-forward-word-backward-word-to-include-symbols-e-g ); and,  `lawlist-forward-paragraph` and `lawlist-backward-paragraph` ( http://superuser.com/questions/643618/how-to-jump-paragraph-up-down-placing-cursor-on-first-visual-line ).