# Make Emacs forward word stop at more points

Tags: emacs, emacs24

One thing I hate about emacs is the default word movement. The following is an example of where I want `M-f` to stop (`M-b` should stop at the same stops):

```
MyFoo myVar = obj->member.my_func(int some_arg);
^ ^   ^ ^   ^ ^  ^ ^     ^^ ^^   ^^   ^   ^^  ^
```

I'm using Emacs 24.3.1 with [Emacs Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude). I have half of the solution with `subword-mode`, which properly handles camel case, and the other half with binding `M-f` to `evil-forward-word-begin`, which properly handles all of the non-camel case stops in the example above. Merging the two solutions would be ideal, but `subword-mode` has no effect on `evil-forward-word-begin`.

I've also tried modifying the syntax table and using `forward-to-word` instead of the default `forward-word` and combining that with subword mode, but 1) that plain didn't work (symbols that I added were still skipped; maybe I did it wrong?), 2) I'd have to add a ton of symbols that are already working fine with `evil-forward-word-begin`, and 3) It would only apply to the syntax table of one language, where I'd like this functionality globally.

Also, I'd like `M-d` (`kill-word`) and `M-DEL` (`backword-kill-word`) to also delete to the stops in the example above.

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while, and I've asked everywhere, including the emacs and evil-mode IRC channels, but I haven't been able to find a solution. Getting this type of word movement would be a huge boost to my productivity.

Comment: Me too!  So, I wrote my own functions several months ago:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/18675201/2112489  Check it out and, if you like it, modify it as you see fit.  The last modification date at the end of my question was done on March 3, 2014 -- i.e., `lawlist-modify-syntax-intro`; `lawlist-modify-syntax-final`; `lawlist-forward-entity`; and `lawlist-backward-entity`.

Comment: Here is the link to my kill-word:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20456861/2112489  And, here is the link to my forward-backward paragraph:  http://superuser.com/a/685604/206164

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My [syntax-subword](https://bitbucket.org/jpkotta/syntax-subword) mode does almost exactly what you want.

```
MyFoo myVar = obj->member.my_func(int some_arg);
^ ^  ^^ ^  ^^^^  ^ ^     ^^ ^^   ^^  ^^   ^^  ^
```

Comment: This is pretty cool. Is there any easy way for me to modify the source to not stop at spaces? That's too much for me.

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of a lot for me too, but I basically never use single character motion, so it works out.  If you want to modify it, look at `forward-syntax`, and do different things based on different syntax changes.

Comment: What if line 167 (https://bitbucket.org/jpkotta/syntax-subword/src/984fe9e526a15d6401f95883c3f102789a929b43/syntax-subword.el?at=default#cl-167) was only executed if `(char-at)` wasn't equal to 32 (a space)? I tried it, and while logging statements say it's working, point doesn't move passed the space. Any idea why?

Comment: In `forward-syntax-or-subword-pos`, `subword-forward` is stopping before (on the space) `forward-syntax`.

Comment: I figured it out. This is the new `forward-syntax-or-subword`: http://pastebin.com/rYX7LH1a. Do you think you could add this to your minor mode? Or maybe just add a setting to turn this functionality on and off? If not, I'll fork the project and apply my fix, since I want to share this with other people.

Comment: Although, there's some error when it hits the end of the file, but it's not a huge deal.

Comment: I've added an option `syntax-subword-skip-spaces', and fixed the end/beginning of buffer error.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. This mode has been working great for the last few days I've been using it. Have you considered putting it on elpa: https://github.com/milkypostman/melpa? People could then install it from the emacs package manager.

Comment: Should be in melpa in a day or two.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest defining functions to assign to the `subword-forward-function` and `subword-backward-function` variables, which check the current situation and then either call the evil function, or the default subword function.

If you're moving forwards, you can use `looking-at` to make the decision; backwards, use `looking-back`.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar:

```
(eval-after-load 'cc-mode
   '(loop for ch from ?A to ?Z by 1
       do (modify-syntax-entry ch "." java-mode-syntax-table)))
```

Comment: This needs some explanation.

Comment: `C-h f modify-syntax-entry RET` or execute: `(info "Syntax Table Concepts(elisp)")`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958397/emacs-delete-whitespaces-or-a-word