# How do I get word-based movements in emacs go-mode to not skip over backquoted strings?

Tags: emacs, go

If I have code like so:

```
func main() {
  a := `line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4`
  fmt.Println(a)
}
```

doing forward-word or backword-word when the cursor is
in the multi-line string moves to the end or the start
of the string respectively.  I'm using go-mode.el v1.3.1
from https://github.com/dominikh/go-mode.el

Similar if the cursor is inside the string and you do

I tried doing

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?` ".")
```

in the go-mode-hook but that didn't change the behavior.

Comment: You can write your own forward/backward word using a syntax-table that is only active during the movement function:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/18675201/2112489

Comment: That looks like overkill. Why doesn't the call to modify-syntax-entry work?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not use `go-mode` and do not have the time available to get into its inner-workings and/or modify the built-in forward/backward words.  There are other movement modes you could look at, like `subword-mode`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Subword-Movement.html  There are already several threads that deal with cursor movement over words/strings/subwords/etc.