# How to test for a syntax condition without moving the cursor?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have been unable to come up with a method to test for a syntax condition without moving the cursor -- e.g., `skip-syntax-forward` and `skip-chars-forward` both move the cursor in order to return `t` or *a positive value*.  How can I return `t` or `nil` without moving the cursor?

```
(defun lawlist-kill-word ()
  "Mark word / symbol + whitespace to the right of the cursor, and kill same."
  (interactive)
  (let* (
    (symbol-regexp "\\s.\\|\\s_")
    (word-regexp "\\sw"))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?' "_") ;; apostrophe = symbol constituent
    (cond
      ((< 0 (skip-syntax-forward "_."))
        (let ((end (point)))
          (set-mark end)
          (while (looking-back symbol-regexp)
            (backward-char))
          (let ((beg (point)))
            (delete-region beg end)
            (setq beg (point))
            (cond
              ((skip-chars-forward " \t")
              (setq end (point))
                (set-mark end)
                (delete-region beg end))))))
      ((< 0 (skip-syntax-forward "w"))
        (let ((end (point)))
          (set-mark end)
          (while (looking-back word-regexp)
            (backward-char))
          (let ((beg (point)))
            (delete-region beg end)
            (setq beg (point))
            (cond
              ((skip-chars-forward " \t")
              (setq end (point))
                (set-mark end)
                (delete-region beg end))))))
      (t
        (let ((beg (point)))
          (set-mark beg)
          (skip-chars-forward " \t")
            (let ((end (point)))
              (delete-region beg end)))
          (deactivate-mark)))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?' "w") ))  ;; apostrophe = word constituent
```

---

**EDIT**:  `lawlist-kill-word` is a work in progress -- any updates to this function will be posted to a thread related to that issue -- i.e.,:  [Emacs: delete whitespaces or a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958397/emacs-delete-whitespaces-or-a-word)

Comment: Moving the cursor (actually the point) is no problem if you wrap it into `save-excursion`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Tobias said: wrap cursor movements in `save-excursion`.  Save any values you want (e.g., of `(point)`) in variables and return them as needed.

E.g., if you want the position four lines ahead, do something like this:

```
(let ((posn  (save-excursion (forward-line 4) (point))))
  posn)
```