# Emacs delete up to the beginning of next word (like Vim 'dw')?

Tags: vim, emacs

So I'm trying to delete some whitespace at the beginning of a line and when I press <kbd>M-d</kbd> I end up removing more content than I need to:

```
   (add-to-list 'load-path
                "~/path-to-yasnippet")
   (require 'yasnippet)
   (yas-global-mode 1)
```

```
^ ^
| |__ want to delete to here    
|
|___ Cursor here
```

I've looked several places but haven't been able to do what Vim's <kbd>dw</kbd> command does.

For instance, Emacs' commands for operating on [words](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Words.html) don't do seem to do it.

Comment: Here is a link to another kill word and/or kill whitespace variation:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20456861/2112489

Comment: Is switching to evil-mode an option ? http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Evil you'll do just like in vim.

Comment: I've been tempted since I already have some vim on my fingers... But don't understand yet why not just to use vim otherwise??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different solutions to this, so here is one:

```lisp
(defun forward-kill-whitespace-or-word ()
  "If `point' is followed by whitespace kill that.
Otherwise call `kill-word'"
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-at "[ \t\n]")
      (let ((pos (point)))
        (re-search-forward "[^ \t\n]" nil t)
        (backward-char)
        (kill-region pos (point)))
    (kill-word 1)))
```

**EDIT:**
p should have been pos.

Comment: Symbol's variable as a value is void p

I just copied it to my .emacs eval the region... it moves the cursor, it it doesn't delete...

Comment: It looks like `p` should be `pos`, but I haven't tried the function.  E.g., `(kill-region pos (point))`

Answer (score 5):

Actually I just found out:

<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd>

Does it for me since I only needed to delete white space.

Comment: This answer would be improved by mentioning that this key is bound (by default) to the function `delete-horizontal-space`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to understand what you want to do:

1. delete whitespace at the beginning of a line
2. delete any characters at the beginning of a line
3. delete any characters up to but not including the beginning of the next word, regardless of where you are on a line and of whether there are any line breaks before the next word
4. mimic the behavior of Vim's `dw` command

I'm choosing to address item 3, since this is what I wanted to do myself.

The action I wanted to perform was equivalent to the following series of commands:

- set-mark-command
- forward-word
- backward-word
- kill-region

This is what I did:

- turned on macro recording
- executed the commands (via their key bindings, but you could execute them via their function names as well)
- saved the macro
- associated a name with that macro
- copied the macro contents to my init file as a function
- associated the function with a key binding

The macro contents look like this:

`;; kill all characters up to but not including the start of the next word
 ;; (unlike kill-word, which kills the next word as well)
    (fset 'my-delete-to-start-of-word
          (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([67108896 C-right C-left delete] 0 "%d")) arg)))`